# merge item with same pcode and count as 1

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem  on how to count on the number of item in my cart to determine how many different items are sold. so let say for example

i have this ff value in my table "sales"

```
id | p_code | p_name | qty |
1  |  1553  |  33uf  |  2  |
2  |  1553  |  33uf  |  3  |
3  |  8812  |   ic   |  1  |
```

the expected output must be something like this.

```
 " the number(s) of item sold : 2 "
```

so why 2? it is because id 1 and 2 are the same product so it count as 1 .. and id 3 is different from the other 2 so it count as 1 also that's why we get the answer 2.

my idea is to sum the qty but i guess it's very wrong. i really don't have idea how to merge item with same pcode. pls pls pls help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a count of distinct p_codes?

> select count(distinct p_code) from sales;

Comment: wow men! it takes almost 1 hour for me to think and still can't get. but you! you solve it in just a few seconds! great!. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

As you are using php, just create an array with `p_code`(s) that you encounter as keys. Each time you encounter a `p_code` do this,

```
arr[p_code]=1;
```

After you have done this for all `p_codes`, just get the length of the array `arr` above. This is going to be the unique number of p_codes that you have.